# How to specify DatePickerDialog locale?

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, locale

I am developing an application on Android. The application has a layout to select a lenguage to use: spanish, portuguese, english, french, italian, german and galician. It works fine but when selected locale is galician, DatePicker dialog is in english. I think that it´s because Android don´t have galician language, how can I change DatePicker dialog to show data in correct locale?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to extend the DatePickerDialog class with your own and set the text in galician.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. Can you explain me how change date format? I want to show day, month and year. I changed DatePickerDialog and now shows title in that format, but date picker is in english format (month, day, year).